# Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Error' in try and catch block Typescript

Tags: typescript, error-handling, axios, try-catch

I am new to typescript, I am trying to handle errors in axios fetch, but in the response which comes as a JSON response, I am not able to handle it correctly.

```
try {
    await axios_auth.put(`${"http://localhost:4500/api" + API_CALL}`, values).then((res) => {

        console.log(res.data.success)
    })


  
} catch (err: any) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
    

        if (err.response.status === 400 && err.response.data.code === "CATEGORY_ALREADY_EXIST") { // Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Error'.
            console.log("Category exists")
        }
        

    } else {
        console.log('Unexpected error', err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the correct types, you can add a check whether the error is an instance of the `AxiosError` class:

```
import { AxiosError } from 'axios' 

..

try {
    // ..
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    if (err instanceof AxiosError) {
      if (
        err.response?.status === 400 &&
        err.response?.data.code === 'CATEGORY_ALREADY_EXIST'
      ) {
        console.log('Category exists')
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Unexpected error', err)
    }
  }
}
```

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3612) contains a few more suggestions.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQB7AgZwKJStOAXzgDN8Q4ByAQ3S0oCgGBjCAO03hgFNO4BeONUwBPNszgAKAJQCAfIgZw4MKCMXLlAei1C6mOKwAm3JUUPUYzABZTueAFxwArmwDWbCAHc2shGeVgEjs8OGAOGGpxbghgtAwcPGg-AM0gqVTNOHsoADooXkgObgB+XM5LZwN+GrgAFgAGBrgAMhbMzRz8wvZMUtyjS2pc424BWsoAYWQAFWwAcQB5ACUATQB9ZAAZZexkABEN7AANAEkAZRnGLOUUm81WDggAG25c54gAc0kpy25P6DqbjoTiYSjSDqEVLEbjPPoaG6PTAvN4fb6UACqbGBYG4zB4RmySSglAANESoBCslDlFCoUA)